# .NET Form Design - Button Group "Photoshop Tool Style"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, controls

If you have ever used an image editing application, you will know there is a group of buttons for selecting the current tool. One tool must be selected at all times, and when a tool is selected, the button stays pressed until a different tool is selected.

I have created a *ToolStrip* control and added my *ToolStripButton* items to it, and set the images. For each button I have set the *CheckOnClick* property to true.

What I was going to do next is subscribe to the *Checked event* of each button and set the other buttons *CheckState* to unchecked. It seems like a kind of hack, though.

Does .NET have a way to accomplish this with the ToolStrip control, or is there a better control to use?

**I am using C# and VS 2010, targeting .NET framework 4**

Answer (score 1):

I thinks there is no way to have tfully automated radio buttons on a ToolStrip.

However, it could be made semi-automated:

In each of your click events call `SetToolButtonsChecked(sender);`

```
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetToolButtonsChecked(sender);
    }
```

which is implemented as:

```
    private static void SetToolButtonsChecked(object sender)
    {
        ToolStripButton btn = sender as ToolStripButton;
        ToolStrip strip = btn.GetCurrentParent();
        foreach (ToolStripItem item in strip.Items)
        {
            if (!(item is ToolStripButton)) continue;
            ToolStripButton btnTemp = item as ToolStripButton;
            if (!btnTemp.CheckOnClick) continue;
            btnTemp.Checked = btnTemp.Equals(btn);
        }
    }
```

This method iterates all buttons on the same toolstrip and sets the Checked property accordingly, if the button has property `CheckOnClick = true`.